# Insert data failed on Laravel one to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try to insert some data in one to many relation and i got this kind of error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'article_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `comments` (`comment`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (this is comment, 2017-10-12 13:14:07, 2017-10-12 13:14:07))
```

here's my router:

```
Route::post('/article/{article}/comment', 'CommentsController@save');
```

here's my controller:

```
public function save(Article $article){
        Comment::create([
            'comment' => request('comment'),
            'article_id' => $article->id
        ]);
        return back();
 }
```

And here is my form that i use to post the data:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="/article/{{ $article->id }}/comment">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="comment" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I try to print my $article->id and it has a value of my article id. but i don't know why it said that it doesn't have value. Thanks.

Comment: Please check 'article_id' field in comment table

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd i already check, and i already put some data manually, and it's work fine.

Comment: Please put default static value in article_id field like: 

Comment::create([
            'comment' => request('comment'),
            'article_id' => 1
        ]);

Comment: Please check its work or not .

Comment: And Please check in *Comment* model filable (i.e protected $fillable = ['comment','article_id'])

Comment: @Addweb i already add into the fillable, and i already try to put the value manually, but i still got the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

Please add below code in `Comment` model and check:

```
protected $fillable = ['comment','article_id'];
```

Comment: @Henra: Please put your comments table structure

Comment: oh not sure what happen but now it's working. strange, it doesn't work at the first time although i already write the fillable.

Comment: @Henra: Glad to help henera and if my answer is your solution then upvote to my answer